# ios widget load remote image url in TimelineProvider?

Tags: image, widget, timeline, ios14

I'm showing a stock chart (eg: https://example.com/my_img.png) on my widget.

As investigation on SO & Apple dev 4rum, I cannot found a workable solution.

As I know, Widget does not support async image loading so my approach is fetching the image at the time we getTimeline(), then pass the image data into Entry to show it later.

But I cannot make it work, can anyone point me out how to resolve it?

In short, it's not working!:

```
// Fetch first in getTimeline()
let imgData = Data(
  contentsOf: URL(string: "https://example.com/my_img.png")!
)!

// Then render it later in  View
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imgData))
```

Here is all my pseudo code:

```
func getTimeline(...) {
  var imageData = nil
  let url: URL = URL(string: "https://example.com/my_img.png")!
  if let imgData:Data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
    imageData = imgData
  }
  
  var entry = SimpleEntry(...)
  entry.imageData = imageData

  let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
  completion(timeline)
}

// Some where in the widget i'll show the imageData above
struct FIM_SV_Chart: View {
  let imageData: Data?
  
  var body: some View {
    if imageData != nil, let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
      Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 80, height: 26.0)
    } else {
      Image("EmptyChart")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 80, height: 26.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault, I generated an incorrect image url so imgData is 0 byte!

This will work:

```
// Fetch first in getTimeline()
let imgData = Data(
  contentsOf: URL(string: "https://example.com/my_img.png")!
)!

// Then render it later in  View
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imgData))
```